# Different Order and Seasonal Order in SARIMAX Model: Implications?

Tags: python, scipy.stats, sarimax

[Link to code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/oenvespa/time-series-eda-xgb-arima-cnn-lstm-cnn-lstm/notebook)

I'm working with time series data and trying to fit a SARIMAX model using the statsmodels library in Python. I've noticed that in the code, the order and seasonal_order parameters are set differently. q-value is different. Why set it like this? Why is it necessary to set both the order and seasonal_order parameters, and why do they have different q-values?

Here's the code snippet:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=(1, 1, 1),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using SARIMA model this means that there is a seasonal component that you want to fit you model on. Actually, SARIMA model is integrating AR,MA,SAR,SMA models within.

In SARIMA (Seasonal AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average) modeling, both the `order` and `seasonal_order` parameters are used to specify the orders of different components of the model.

1. **`order` (Non-Seasonal Order)**:

   - The `order` parameter specifies the orders of the non-seasonal components of the SARIMA model.
   - It is denoted as `(p, d, q)`, where:

     - `p` represents the order of the AutoRegressive (AR) component, which captures the linear relationship between the current observation and its past values.
     - `d` represents the order of differencing required to make the time series stationary. It indicates how many differences you need to take to achieve stationarity.
     - `q` represents the order of the Moving Average (MA) component, which captures the linear relationship between the current observation and past white noise (residuals) terms.
2. **`seasonal_order` (Seasonal Order)**:

   - The `seasonal_order` parameter specifies the orders of the seasonal components of the SARIMA model.
   - It is denoted as `(P, D, Q, s)`, where:

     - `P` represents the seasonal order of the Seasonal AutoRegressive (SAR) component, which captures the seasonal linear relationship between the current observation and its past values separated by a seasonal period `s`.
     - `D` represents the seasonal order of differencing for seasonal stationarity.
     - `Q` represents the seasonal order of the Seasonal Moving Average (SMA) component, which captures the seasonal linear relationship between the current observation and past white noise (residuals) separated by a seasonal period `s`.

Comment: Thanks，but  what happens when both the order and seasonal_orter parameters are set simultaneously？If I have knew the time series is seasonal，why need to set order parameter？Can I only set the seasonal_orter？

Comment: from your comment it appears that you don't understand the basics of ARIMA models, so please refer to a book (e.g. practical time series analysis)